# Configuring the colors of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, themes, colors

Since there is no easy way to switch color theme in Eclipse I'm wondering if there are any themes that have documented their colors. Kind of like this:
Background: #000000
brackets: #FFEFC6
So i manually can configure the theme without having to mess around with a color picker. I need a dark theme similar to TextMates vibrant theme.

Comment: Look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse. Essentially, Eclipse sucks in that regard.

Comment: Yup, I'm with you on that. That's why it would be nice with some kind of schematic document I could copy paste from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try exporting/importing properties?
 File / Import / General / Properties

I don't know if there are downloadable property exports though.

Comment: Yes, i have messed around with importing peoples settings but funky things happens and eclipse crashes so I'm leaving that approach.